# Mongodb installation error on windows 7 dll missing

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB in my system windows 7 64 bit. whenever I try to run the mongod application or type the command `mongod --dbpath "db"` I get an error saying `The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing in your computer.`
I reinstalled multiple times and tried other means but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: I suggest [actually following the instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). Looks like you have not. Installer packages tend to take care of these sort of things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows Update from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) for your OS. Then install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redist. Restart the pc and run mongodb files(mongod or any).